# linear regression using tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, linear-regression

```
import tensorflow as tf

M = tf.Variable([0.01],tf.float32)
b = tf.Variable([1.0],tf.float32)

#inputs and outputs

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32) # actual value of y which we already know

Yp = M * x + b # y predicted value

#loss

squareR = tf.square(Yp - y)
loss =  tf.reduce_sum(squareR)

#optimize

optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01)
train = optimizer.minimize(loss)

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init)

for i in range(1000):
    sess.run(train,{x:[1,2,3,4,5],y:[1.9,2.4,3.7,4.9,5.1]})
print(sess.run([M,b]))
```

output

```
[array([ 0.88999945], dtype=float32), array([ 0.93000191], dtype=float32)]
```

Problem:
when I am changing the values of x and y to

```
x:[100,200,300,400,500],y:[19,24,37,49,51]
```

then the output is:

```
[array([ nan], dtype=float32), array([ nan], dtype=float32)]
```

please help me out to get slope and y-intercept of linear model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding some print statements to your training loop, we can see what's going on during training:

```
for i in range(1000):
    _, mm, bb = sess.run([train,M,b],{x:[100,200,300,400,500],y:[19,24,37,49,51]})
    print(mm, bb)
    if np.isnan(mm):
      break
print(sess.run([M,b]))
```

The output:

```
[ 1118.01000977] [ 4.19999981]
[-12295860.] [-33532.921875]
[  1.35243170e+11] [  3.68845632e+08]
[ -1.48755065e+15] [ -4.05696309e+12]
[  1.63616896e+19] [  4.46228634e+16]
[ -1.79963571e+23] [ -4.90810521e+20]
[  1.97943407e+27] [  5.39846559e+24]
[ -2.17719537e+31] [ -5.93781625e+28]
[  2.39471499e+35] [  6.53105210e+32]
[-inf] [-inf]
[ nan] [ nan]
```

That output means your training is diverging. In this case, lowering the learning rate is one of the possible approaches to fix the problem.

Lowering the learning rate to `0.000001` works, these are the learned M and b after 1000 iterations:

```
[array([ 0.11159456], dtype=float32), array([ 1.01534212], dtype=float32)]
```

Comment: But the slope and y intercept are incorrect. The values of M = 0.089 and b= 9.3

Comment: Might need more than 1000 steps for training, or it might have ended up in a sub-optimal solution since the learning rate is extremely slow.
Try changing optimizer and/or parameters, but the original issue was the divergence of the optimizer, which happens if the LR is too big.